# Xpath simplification: extract text of self and child node

Tags: xpath

Having this HTML-snippet

```
<td class="info">self-text
<br>
<b>child-text</b>
</td>
```

I would like to extract `self-text` and `child-text`.
So far i am using this regex:

```
.//td[contains(@class, 'info')]/text() | .//td[contains(@class, 'info')]/b/text()
```

Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression which will return *all non-empty* text nodes *anywhere* within the outer `td` element :

```
.//td[contains(@class, 'info')]//text()[normalize-space()]
```